# Synchronization thumbs with parent

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I want to sync the child gallery with the main one. Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt9c3be8/3/), but I have a [glitch](https://gyazo.com/271c021819752da5b392b757722e5e06) with a loop mod. Is there a ready-made solution for such an idea, or can you tell me what is wrong. I understand why such a [glitch](https://gyazo.com/271c021819752da5b392b757722e5e06) arises, but I do not know how to get around it and whether it is even possible to do this. I would be glad to have any hints.

```
galleryThumbs.on('slideChange', function () {
  galleryTop.slideToLoop(galleryThumbs.realIndex);
});
```